# MS Word page numbers with a specific format

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to add page numbers to a document that have 5 digits all the time (i.e. 00001, 00002,... 00153)

MS Word does not natively allow for such a specific numbering convention. Is there a way to do this with VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field code can actually be generated fairly simply by using a ***numeric formatting switch***:

```
{ PAGE \# "00000" }
```

Comment: Darn, and I've been using IF fields all this time. Is there a good resource for non-field-specific switches?

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Does the information on http://www.gmayor.com/formatting_word_fields.htm help? Search the topic **Format (\*) fieldswitch** and go on from there.

Answer (score 1):

VBA isn't necessary to achieve this. Just use nested [IF fields](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-field-9f79e82f-e53b-4ff5-9d2c-ae3b22b7eb5e).

[image]

Comment: Wow! Now _that's_ a field!